# Les 20 et les 80

Tags: usage, prononciation, nombres, mathématiques, régionalismes

L’an dernier, j’ai travaillé avec plusieurs Africains, de différents pays : Côte d’Ivoire, Guinée, Maroc, Tunisie. Comme notre travail impliquait beaucoup de discussions avec des données numériques, j’ai pu constater à ma grande surprise que tous, sans exception, nommaient les nombres de la dizaine des quatre-vingt exactement comme celle des vingt qui serait préfixée d’un quatre.

Nous avions donc droit à des 88 prononcés /katʁə.vɛ̃t.ɥit/, et plus surprenant encore des 81 auxquels était ajouté un *et* : /katʁə.vɛ̃t.e.œ̃/. Nous avions d’ailleurs eu un désaccord sur ce dernier nombre : malgré leur utilisation du *et*, j’étais absolument convaincu qu’ils connaissaient la norme habituelle, mais il me fallu la leur prouver, dictionnaire et Wikipédia à l’appui (les grammaires sont plus rares en milieu de travail).

J’ai donc cru comprendre qu’il s’agissait là de l’enseignement habituel du français en Afrique (pour tous ces collègues, le français fut une langue d’enseignement, mais pas une langue maternelle).

> - Le français est-il vraiment enseigné ainsi dans certains pays africains ?
> - Quelqu’un d’ailleurs reconnaît-il son usage personnel ou celui d’un proche dans ces exemples ?

Comment: Sans pouvoir vraiment y répondre, je constaterais qu'une telle habitude n'exige pas d'enseignment direct (malgré l'explication y faisant référence), mais tout simplement un usage courant. Je suis enclin à croire que *quatre-vingt*, plutôt que d'être employé de façon systématiquement erronée, serait relexicalisé selon une analogie avec les autres nombres : ceci est susceptible de se produire dans la parole de tous jes jours. Les exceptions ont tendance à « s'aplanir » faute de motivation pour respecter le statut étymologique (quasiment disparu même en français standard dans ce cas).

Comment: Cela peut-il être un usage courant dans tant de pays où le français constitue primordialement une langue politique et institutionnelle? Peut-être bien que oui malgré tout. Je suis toujours frappé par la manière qu'ont bien des peuples ayant appartenu à l'empire britannique de nommer les chiffres et nombres en anglais. Le français s'est-il insinué ainsi dans les parlers locaux d'Afrique? Quoique cette explication me semble improbable pour la Tunisie et le Maroc (la langue arabe a une immense et très ancienne culture mathématique), ça demeurerait possible pour la Côte d'Ivoire et la Guinée.

Comment: _Quatre-vingt-et-un_ me semble inusité en Europe, au  mieux relégué à de petites régions isolées. Il existe cependant un autre système qui serait cohérent avec les autres dizaines: septante, huitante et nonante. En dépit de ses incontestables avantages, pourtant, cette approche ne réussit pas à s'imposer et demeure pour beaucoup une simple curiosité régionale. Pourquoi un peuple adoptant les nombres français n'élirait-il pas le meilleur de ses systèmes, plutôt que de semi-régulariser le moins intuitif? Il est vrai qu'une logique trop simpliste rencontre vite ses limites en linguistique...

Comment: Oui, la logique interne de la faculté langagière prévale souvent sur l'uniformité mondiale. :) La plupart du temps il faut un emploi très fréquent pour conserver des irrégularités marquantes, c’est-à-dire que les mots comme « être, avoir, aller » garderont leurs conjugaisons exceptionnelles tandis que « tirer » non. Les nombres se trouvent entre les deux côtés, mais là on a aussi la tendance d’un système de nombres à se régulariser vu qu’il y a un très grand nombre de lexèmes dont il faut tenir compte. L'étrange à mon sens est qu'une si grande partie de la Francophonie garde cette exception !

Comment: Une régularisation récente à la norme: au Québec il y a encore vingt ans, la façon de compter les 60-70 «soixante et deux, soixante et trois, ..., soixante et dix, ..., soixante et dix-neuf» était omniprésente. À force d'insistance (de qui, pourtant?), cette tournure est désormais en sévère régression et la grande majorité de ses fidèles compte au moins un demi siècle de bougies sur leur gâteau. Selon LBU14§593, avant Oudin et sa _Grammaire françoise_ (1632), il était courant d'ajouter **et** pour toute opération additive (mil et sept cent), mais l'omission s'est tôt manifestée.

Comment: Fascinant. (Peut-être un exemple d'un contexte caracterisé par des irrégularités qui aide à conserver un ancien usage.)

Comment: La disjonction crée des termes et /katʁə.vɛ̃t.ɥit/ se rapproche par exemple d'un montant d'argent où on prononcerait faiblement la conj. _et_ avec l'omission du nom de la monnaie (4.28$) ; ou comment on prononce la combinaison chapitre/verset d'une référence à un passage de la Bible (Marc 4:28) ou autrement pour moi ça créé une détermination par multiplication des termes (4 (x) 28 = 112). C'est surprenant...

Comment: @LukeSawczak 75¢ était probablement le prix habituel de plusieurs choses et l'argent comptant était beaucoup plus présent qu'il ne l'est aujourd'hui, surreprésentant peut-être ce nombre par rapport à d'autres et permettant à cette ancienne forme de survivre jusqu'à l'ère des cartes de débit et des bitcoins. Qui sait?

Comment: @deLaDauversière Le R de quatre n'est jamais omis dans 80, 81, etc., non plus que dans 4ème ou quatrièmement, mais souvent dans presque tous ses autres usages, du moins au Québec (quat’ cents, ent’ quat’ z’yeux, quat’ plusse quat’, dans quat’ dodos c'est Noël, le quat’ juillet deux mille quat’). On pourra penser à «J'ai quatre ans», mais la présence d'une voyelle n'explique pas tout (mes quat’ amis m'attendaient). 4,28$ s'exprimera le plus souvent «Ça f'ra quat’ et vingt-huit». Tout ça pour dire que /katʁə.vɛ̃t.ɥit/, surtout dans le contexte, ne sonnait pas comme 4,28$. Intéressant néanmoins.

Answer (score 3):

Pour répondre uniquement à la première de ces deux questions...

Mon père, pour éviter le service militaire, a enseigné le Français pendant quelques années au Niger. Il n'est plus tout jeune, et cela a du avoir lieu au début des années 70, mais si lesdits Africains avec qui tu travailles ont autour de la cinquantaine, ça pourrait coller...

Je n'ai cependant jamais entendu mon père dire "80 ET 1", je pense qu'on peut donc en conclure qu'il a enseigné la prononciation 80 1 et pas 80 et 1 à ses élèves.

Cet exemple ne fait pas loi, mais il est en tout cas authentique !

Comment: Mes collègues étaient tous plus jeunes que ça, le plus vieux ayant dû commencer sa scolarité vers la fin des années ’70, et le plus jeune sortant tout juste de l’université. Merci néanmoins pour votre réponse. Je ne sais pas si mes collègues ont généralement eu des professeurs européens ou africains, je suppose que ce devait être un peu des deux. C’est tout de même un point de départ. Est-ce là une prononciation courante ou au moins occasionnelle dans votre région?